# Android: Storing int and String values in one multidimensional array

Tags: android, string, multidimensional-array, int

is it possible to store different values into a multidimensional array such as int's and String's?

```
String[][] mainArray= new String[2][2];

    mainArray[0][0] = 1;
    mainArray[0][1] = "Name1";
    mainArray[1][0] = 2;
    mainArray[1][1] = "Name2";
```

this obviously doesn't work because 1 and 2 are not String values

Answer (score 2):

yes you can store 
try this

```
        String[][] mainArray= new String[2][2];

        mainArray[0][0] = String.valueOf(1);
        mainArray[0][1] = "Name1";
        mainArray[1][0] = String.valueOf(2);
        mainArray[1][1] = "Name2";
```

Comment: The values of 1 and 2 still appear to be strings in this code. When I add the two together, i get the result of 12 ("1"+"2") and not 3 (1+2)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Object` array, and save `Integer`s, which is the boxing of the primitive `int`.

```
Object[][] arr = new Object[2][2];
arr[0][0] = "hello";
arr[0][1] = Integer.valueOf(1);
arr[1][0] = Integer.valueOf(2);
arr[1][1] = "world";
```

Comment: My fault for not pointing this out earlier. I need to be able to sort the array. From what I understand, Objects are not sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
Object[][] arr=new Object[anysize][]; and you can do like this
arr[0][0]=1;
arr[1][0]="hello";
```

But while accessing this array you should also do this using **Object** only.Else there may be ClassCastException.